# How do I setup my @resultBuilder to work with ForEach, but still respect the protocol?

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, foreach, protocols

I have the below containers that I've defined in my project, the first one works, however the second one does not because it throws the following error.

> Argument type 'ForEach<Range<Array.Index>, Range<Array.Index>.Element, PageX>' (aka 'ForEach<Range, Int, PageX>') does not conform to expected type 'PageXItem'

The `@PageBuilder` is implemented on my `NavX` struct like this.

> ```
> @PageBuilder private var content: () -> Content
> ```

I expect to be able to use a standalone `PageX` or a dynamic collection, by using `ForEach`. It does not matter wether it's a `ForEach(array.indices)` or any sequence for that matter, such that each element of the `ForEach` is guaranteed to be a `PageX`.

```
NavX {
   PageX {
   }
}
```

OR

```
NavX {
   ForEach(...) { _ in 
      PageX {...}
   }
}
```

This is the currently used `@PageBuilder`. The last two are my recent attempts at getting this working, with none proving to be successful.

```
@resultBuilder
public struct PageBuilder {

    /// Builds a collection of `PageXItem` views.
    ///
    /// - Parameter components: A variadic list of views conforming to `PageXItem`.
    /// - Returns: An array of views that conform to `PageXItem`.
    static public func buildBlock(_ components: any PageXItem...) -> [any PageXItem] {
        components
    }

    /// Builds a collection of `PageXItem` views, particularly useful for conditional view constructions.
    ///
    /// - Parameter components: A variadic list of arrays of views conforming to `PageXItem`.
    /// - Returns: An array of views that conform to `PageXItem`.
    static public func buildPartialBlock(_ components: [any PageXItem]...) -> [any PageXItem] {
        components.flatMap { $0 }
    }
    
    static public func buildFinalResult(_ component: [any PageXItem]) -> [any PageXItem] {
        component
    }
    
    static public func buildBlock<C: View>(_ component: ForEach<[any PageXItem], UUID, C>) -> ForEach<[any PageXItem], UUID, C> {
        component
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @user1046037 no unfortunately not.

Comment: What is the definition of PageX? Your ForEach iterates over a sequence of PageX, while the expected type is PageXItem.

Answer (score 1):

To work with `ForEach` you should comply with the following requirements:

1. Your struct must conform to `View` (if it doesn't) because `ForEach` works with views only.

```swift
struct Item {
  let name: String
}

extension Item: View {
  public var body: Never {
    fatalError()
  }
}
```

2. Your `@resultBuilder` must operate with a dedicated protocol only.

```swift
protocol ItemConvertible {
  var items: [Item] { get }
}

extension Item: ItemConvertible {
  var items: [Item] {
    [self]
  }
}

@resultBuilder
struct ItemsBuilder {
  static func buildBlock(_ components: ItemConvertible...) -> [ItemConvertible] {
    components
  }
  
  static func buildFinalResult(_ components: [ItemConvertible]) -> [Item] {
    components.flatMap(\.items)
  }
}
```

3. Your should extend `ForEach` with the protocol.

```swift
extension ForEach: ItemConvertible where Content == Item {
  var items: [Item] {
    data.map(content)
  }
}
```

Now you can write your builder function:

```swift
@ItemsBuilder
func content() -> [Item] {
  Item(name: "1")
  Item(name: "2")
  ForEach(3..<5) {
    Item(name: "\($0)")
  }
}

print(content()) // [Item(name: "1"), Item(name: "2"), Item(name: "3"), Item(name: "4")]
```